# ¿Cómo validar un TextBox de sólo números en SmartGWT?

Tags: java, smartgwt

My TextBox está dentro de un formulario y solo debería aceptar números, pero no quiero utilizar *Handlers* para hacer la válidacion como:

```
ChangedHandler/ Changehandler/ KeyPressHandler / etc...
```

Sino que quiero hacerlo de la manera recomendada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo tu TextBox al final lo que es es un **TextItem** en un **DynamicForm**, esto se haría así:

```
IsIntegerValidator isIntegerValidator = new IsIntegerValidator();
isIntegerValidator.setErrorMessage("Mensaje de error");
textItem.setValidators(isIntegerValidator);
```

Como dato extra: Si lo que quieres es mostrar los errores a nivel de formulario cuando llamas a **form.validate()** lo que tienes que hacer es setear la propiedad **setShowInlineErrors(true**) al formulario.